# Finding JSON objects inside a string

Tags: java, android, regex, json

Following my question about a [me having to deal with a poorly implemented chat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453233/android-reading-from-socket-hangs-on-second-read-loop), I have come to the conclusion that I should try to get the chat messages out of the other server responses.

Basically, I receive a string that would look like this:

```
13{"ts":2135646,"msg":"{\"ts\":123156,\"msg\":\"this is my chat {message 1\"}","sender":123,"recipient":321}45{"ts":2135646,"msg":"{\"ts\":123156,\"msg\":\"this is my chat} message 2\"}","sender":123,"recipient":321}1
```

And the result I would like is two substrings:

```
{"ts":2135646,"msg":"{\"ts\":123156,\"msg\":\"this is my chat {message 1\"}","sender":123,"recipient":321}
{"ts":2135646,"msg":"{\"ts\":123156,\"msg\":\"this is my chat} message 2\"}","sender":123,"recipient":321}
```

The output I can receive is a mix between JSON objects (possibly containing other JSON objects) and some numerical data.

I need to extract the JSON objects from that string.

I have thought about counting curly braces to pick what is between the first opening one and the corresponding closing one. However, the messages can possibly contain a curly brace.

I have thought about regular expressions but I can't get one that will work (I am not good at regexes)

Any idea about how to proceed?

Comment: I take it that the JSON objects themselves don't contain any braces (i. e. nested objects) other than those within quotes? And that quoted strings may also contain escaped quotes?

Comment: In the example I gave, you have a nested escaped JSON object withing the parent JSONObject. The "msg" part of the nested JSON Object can contain any character (curly brace, quotes, ...).

Comment: OK, as long as that's always within a string, a regex will work. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "\\{           # Match an opening brace.                              \n" +
    "(?:           # Match either...                                      \n" +
    " \"           #  a quoted string,                                    \n" +
    " (?:          #  which may contain either...                         \n" +
    "  \\\\.       #   escaped characters                                 \n" +
    " |            #  or                                                  \n" +
    "  [^\"\\\\]   #   any other characters except quotes and backslashes \n" +
    " )*           #  any number of times,                                \n" +
    " \"           #  and ends with a quote.                              \n" +
    "|             # Or match...                                          \n" +
    " [^\"{}]*     #  any number of characters besides quotes and braces. \n" +
    ")*            # Repeat as needed.                                    \n" +
    "\\}           # Then match a closing brace.", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

Comment: won't work. your regex can't match a json object in a json object e.g. {"toto": {"a": 1, "b": 2}}

Comment: @njzk2: I know, that's why I asked MarvinLabs whether those "nested" JSON objects would always be enclosed within strings. He said yes, or at least that's how I understand his answer. This regex works on the example string provided which does contain a "nested" JSON object.

Comment: Works nicely so far. Thanks a bunch!